# prepare statement fatal error

Tags: php, prepared-statement

```
<?php
//Defining page title
define('WEBSITE_TITLE', 'Register');

//Content location
$content = 'content/register.php';

//Database connection
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=saldev', 'admin', '420blazeit');
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die();
}

//Including website template
include_once 'template.php';


if(isset($_POST['submitRegister'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $rank = 'user';


    $ins = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO 'users'('username', 'password', 'email', 'rank') VALUES (''username','password', 'email','user')");
    $ins->execute();
    echo 'Success! you have been register';
    header("Location: index.php");
    }
?>
```

I get the following error: "Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\workspace\register.php on line 23"

I have been trying to find out what the problem is, but I haven't got a clue how to fix this. Somebody please help! :c

Comment: Why you wrote $dbh = null;??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two single quotes `'`. Replace

```
$ins = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO 'users'('username', 'password', 'email', 'rank') VALUES (''username','password', 'email','user')");
```

to

```
$ins = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, rank) VALUES ('username','password', 'email','user')");
```

Also remove `$dbh = null;`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you setting `null` on `$dbh`

```
$dbh = null;
```

Also you should not use `'` inside the mysql query for tables or columns names.